# Python, display images located in sub directories with jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, glob

I'm trying to display images located in different sub directories.

I'm trying this code:

```
files = glob.glob('Ensemble/*/*', recursive = True) 
for file in files: 
    print(file) #This print the path of all the images 
    for j in file.glob("*.jpg"):
       image = cv2.imread(str(j))
       plt.imshow(image)
       plt.show()
```

Output:

```
Ensemble\Cercles\Cercle2
Ensemble\Cercles\Cercle3
Ensemble\Cercles\Cercle4
Ensemble\Cercles\Cercle5
Ensemble\Diamants\Diamant2
Ensemble\Diamants\Diamant3
Ensemble\Diamants\Diamant4
Ensemble\Diamants\Diamant5
Ensemble\Hexagones\Hexagone2
Ensemble\Hexagones\Hexagone3
Ensemble\Hexagones\Hexagone4
Ensemble\Hexagones\Hexagone5
Ensemble\Triangles\Triangle2
Ensemble\Triangles\Triangle3
Ensemble\Triangles\Triangle4
Ensemble\Triangles\Triangle5
```

I get easily the the path of all images, with this code. But how to display the images?

I have this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-c624a5120e94> in <module>
     22     #plt.show()
     23     #type(image)
---> 24     for j in file.glob("*.jpg"):
     25         image = cv2.imread(str(j))
     26         plt.imshow(image)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'glob'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `for j in file.glob("*.jpg"):` to the following:

```py
if file.endswith(".jpg"):
```

And change `image = cv2.imread(str(j))` to the following

```
image = cv2.imread(file)
```